# If one join works per rep id, don't join next

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am matching two datasets that I imported into a Redshift DB: both are at rep id level.

This is my initial query to match the two datasets:

```
select * 
from #t t
join #t2 t2
on lower(trim(t.unique_id))=lower(trim(t2.unique_id))
or lower(trim(t.email))=lower(trim(t2.email)) 
or lower(trim(split_part(t.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t.last_name,',',1)))=lower(trim(split_part(t2.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t2.last_name,',',1)))
```

`#t` is the source of truth I am matching to, and `unique_id` is supposedly the universal identifier (though only matches about 60%) for rep id (internal identifier), however, in some cases `#t2` table has (incorrectly) multiple `unique_id`s per rep, and incorrectly multiple `email`s.

How can I change it so that it is more restrictive, ie. when getting a match by `unique_id`- dont match next record for that rep, when matching by `email`- dont match next record for that rep, and lastly join by firstname/lastname.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to skin this cat. As one option you could add a rank for each join as a CASE statement, and then pick out the one that has the min rank:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        min(ranktest) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.unique_id) as minrank
    FROM
    (
        select *,
        CASE WHEN lower(trim(t.unique_id))=lower(trim(t2.unique_id)) THEN 1
             WHEN lower(trim(t.email))=lower(trim(t2.email))  THEN 2 
             WHEN ower(trim(split_part(t.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t.last_name,',',1)))=lower(trim(split_part(t2.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t2.last_name,',',1))) THEN 3 
             END as ranktest
        from #t t
            join #t2 t2
                on lower(trim(t.unique_id))=lower(trim(t2.unique_id))
                or lower(trim(t.email))=lower(trim(t2.email)) 
                or lower(trim(split_part(t.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t.last_name,',',1)))=lower(trim(split_part(t2.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t2.last_name,',',1)))
    ) sub1
WHERE ranktest = minrank;
```

You could also do this by querying twice, once to get your data, and once to get the min(ranktest). It will almost definitely be slower, but.. it's a little prettier:

```
WITH subquery AS
(
    select *,
            CASE WHEN lower(trim(t.unique_id))=lower(trim(t2.unique_id)) THEN 1
                 WHEN lower(trim(t.email))=lower(trim(t2.email))  THEN 2 
                 WHEN ower(trim(split_part(t.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t.last_name,',',1)))=lower(trim(split_part(t2.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t2.last_name,',',1))) THEN 3 
                 END as ranktest
            from #t t
                join #t2 t2
                    on lower(trim(t.unique_id))=lower(trim(t2.unique_id))
                    or lower(trim(t.email))=lower(trim(t2.email)) 
                    or lower(trim(split_part(t.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t.last_name,',',1)))=lower(trim(split_part(t2.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t2.last_name,',',1)))
)
SELECT *
FROM subquery t1
WHERE t1.ranktest = (SELECT min(ranktest) FROM subquery WHERE subquery.unique_id = t1.ranktest)
```

Alternatively, you could run this as a UNION ALL, testing for the join differently each time to avoid repeats and only allowing the top most ranked join through:

```
select *
from #t t
    join #t2 t2
        on lower(trim(t.unique_id))=lower(trim(t2.unique_id))
UNION ALL
select *
from #t t
    join #t2 t2
        on lower(trim(t.unique_id))<>lower(trim(t2.unique_id))
        AND lower(trim(t.email))=lower(trim(t2.email)) 
UNION ALL
select *
FROM #t t
    join #t2 t2
        ON lower(trim(t.unique_id))<>lower(trim(t2.unique_id))
        AND lower(trim(t.email))<>lower(trim(t2.email)) 
        AND lower(trim(split_part(t.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t.last_name,',',1)))=lower(trim(split_part(t2.first_name,',',1))||trim(split_part(t2.last_name,',',1)))
```

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem. I'll wait to accept to allow people to provide a possible simpler solution  :)

Comment: No worries. I've added a couple other ways to do this. I'm certain there are more ways to go about this, each with their pros and cons. I'm still kind of partial to first one though. It's a single pass to join, then an additional to do the rank comparison and if more join attempts are made, you only need edit the CASE statement to match where the UNION can get a little hairy.

Comment: thank you for this. #1 worked for me but it gave some duplicates because of the third type of match- something that I have to correct for manually and nothing we can do programatically. #2 returns nothing because of the `where t1.ranktest = (select .. from .. where unique_id=ranktest)` condition which is a typo. #3 actually returns duplicates in the last join because there are records where email<>email and unique_id<>unique_id but firstname\lastname matches; this is actually taken care of in #1 but not here

Comment: also, I realized when I change your join in the first version to left join, it still only returns the records that matched. I basically took your query then "union all" to your query again (rename a) and right join to #t1 where a.rep_id is null (and add null for columns not existent in #t1). There has to be a better way